# Class Cast Execption when Trying to Add Object array as Component in Java Swing

Tags: java, arrays, swing, components, classcastexception

I have a `JFrame` which has many `LayredPane's` and those `LayerdPane's` has many `JPanel's` in it.

i have more than 50 `JPanel's` in the a Single Layered Pane where i want to switch the panels according to my `JCombobox` selected index.

so i have copied all the Panel Variable names as String Array and pass the Panel Variable name as per the `JCombobox` index number name.

```
Object Array with Panel Variable Names

public Object panelNames[]={
    "clinicalPathalogyReport",
    "clinicalHaematologyReport",
    "clinicalSerologyReport",
    "clinicalSerologyReport",
    "clinicalSerologyReport",
    "clinicalSerologyReport",
    "clinicalBiochemistryReport",
    "clinicalHaemotologyReport",
    "clinicalBiochemistryReport1",
    "clinicalBiochemistryReport2",
    "clinicalBiochemistryReport3",
    "clinicalHaemotologyReport2",
    "urinePregnancyTest",
    "completeBloodPicture",
    "clinicalPathalogyReport1",
    "clinicalBiochemistryReport4",
    "clinicalBiochemistryReport5"};
```

So i want to pass the Variable name with my Selected index

so here is my source code to perform action

```
int i=uniqueTests.getSelectedIndex();

                ltlayeredPane.removeAll();
                ltlayeredPane.add((Component)panelNames[i]);
                ltlayeredPane.repaint();
                ltlayeredPane.revalidate();
```

But i am having Class Cast Exception

Comment: The elements of the array `panelNames` are `String` objects. You are trying to cast a `String` object to `Component`. Since a `String` is not a `Component`, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: is there any way to over come this, because i have more JPanels

Comment: You can use Java Reflection package

Comment: You can create an array (or list) of Components `public Components[] panels` and add the actual components to that array.